# Sharing on WhatsApp in Swift 3.0 Error: Contextual member 'urlHostAllowed' has no associated value

Tags: swift, swift3

I just upgraded my swift project to swift 3.

I've been using the following function to share the app on Whatsapp, but I couldn't understand the error that occurred after the upgrade

This is the function code:

```
func shareOnWhatsapp() {
    let urlString = "Greetings,\n\nThis is the XYZ App link, I hope you find it useful!\n\nhttp://itunes.apple.com/app/idxxxxxxxx"
    let urlStringEncoded = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed())
    let url  = URL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=\(urlStringEncoded!)")

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
    }

}
```

The error says:

```
Contextual member 'urlHostAllowed' has no associated value
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: `urlHostAllowed`, not `urlHostAllowed()`.

Comment: that solved the problem! I had no idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get rid of the  "()" in the third line:

```
let urlStringEncoded = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed())
```

to this:

```
let urlStringEncoded = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
```